# Does Novikov additivity hold for topological manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Recall that Novikov additivity of signature of compact oriented smooth $4k$-manifolds is the following statement :

If two manifolds are glued by an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism of their boundaries, then the signature of their union is the sum of their signatures.

**Question.** Does this additivity hold for topological manifolds? For example, in dimension $4$. I was not able to find a reference.

Comment: I might be missing something, but Ranicky's argument here http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/slides/maslov1.pdf does not seem to use smoothness at all.

Comment: With more detail (in 4-dimensional case) the proof appears in Kirby's book "The topology of 4-manifolds" on page 29. At some point, Kirby uses smoothness, but only along the 3-dimensional manifold (the common boundary of the two pieces), so it is not a problem. Furthermore, general transversality theory for 4-manifolds was worked out by Freedman and Quinn.

Comment: Misha, many thanks for these references! Indeed, the argument in Ranicky's talk never mentions smoothness, so I believe this answers my question.